# Degree of $\mathbb{Q}(2^{\frac{1}{3}},\omega)$ over $\mathbb{Q}(2^{\frac{1}{3}})$

Tags: field-theory, extension-field, irreducible-polynomials, minimal-polynomials, splitting-field

Consider $f(x) = x^3 - 2 \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$.

The roots of $f(x)$ are $2^{\frac{1}{3}}, 2^{\frac{1}{3}}\omega, 2^{\frac{1}{3}}{\omega}^2$.

$\mathbb{Q}(2^{\frac{1}{3}},\omega)$ is the minimal splitting field of $f(x)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

What is degree of $\mathbb{Q}(2^{\frac{1}{3}},\omega)$ over $\mathbb{Q}(2^{\frac{1}{3}})$?

I have been told that the degree is $3$ because it satisfies degree $3$ irreducible polynomial. But how were we able to come to that conclusion?

Comment: It should be degree $2$. Think about the minimal polynomial for $\omega$ over $\mathbb Q$. Does this minimal polynomial factor over $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]{2})$?

Comment: You may find interesting https://youtu.be/oDwtx5aDkKU?t=955

Answer (score 1):

We know that

$$|\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/3},w):\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/3})| \leq |\mathbb{Q}(w):\mathbb{Q}| = 2.$$

So $|\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/3},w):\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/3})| \in \{1,2\}.$ But if $|\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/3},w):\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/3})| = 1$ then $w \in \mathbb{Q}(2^{1/3})$ which of course isn't true.

Explicitly finding a minimal polynomial for $w$ over $\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/3})$ would be doable, but often this approach is relatively painful compared to the above approach. The idea is the use the inequality stated in the first line. (It holds since any polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$ with $w$ has a root is also a polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/3})$ with $w$ as a root).

Comment: Finding the minimal polynomial is nothing painful. It's the same as the minimal polynomial of $w$ over $\Bbb Q$, i.e. $x^2 + x + 1$.

Comment: I think I mean to say in general finding minimal polynomials for these types of questions is relatively painful when compared to using said inequality.

Comment: I am unable to understand from where we get this inequality?

Comment: The idea is that if you have the minimal polynomial, say $f$ with $\deg f = n$ for $w$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ then we already have a potential candidate for the minimal polynomial for $w$ over $\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/3})$ and of course then the minimal polynomial $g$ here can't have degree larger than $n.$ It's a standard result in Galois theory.

Comment: I have just started studying Galois Theory. But I understand your point. Thank you! It would be really helpful if you could suggest from where I can study more about this result.

Comment: D. J. H. Garling, A Course in Galois Theory is a good book and it is in there. I don't know of any online resources unfortunately but any set of lecture notes or book on Galois theory will have this result

Answer (score 0):

> I have been told that the degree is 3 because it satisfies degree 3 irreducible polynomial.

The number $\omega$ is a root of the cubic $x^3-1$. But that is not irreducible. One factor is $x^2+x+1$, which $\omega$ is a root of.

The minimal polynomial of $\omega$ (be it over $\mathbb{Q}$ or $\mathbb{Q(2^{1/3})}$) has degree $2$, not $3$.